# How to: Excel 2003 macro to sum visible values only?

Tags: excel, sum, visibility, excel-2003, vba

at the moment, I have a very large spreadsheet (40k+ rows), the data includes columns for "name", "date" and "value". the format is uniform.
I want to be able to sum all "values" with the same "name" and "date".
E.g.:

```
Name date value
peter 201103 7
pan 201103 9
felix 201104 9
peter 201104 12
peter 201104 17
```

Now, I want to sum the value for all "peter" with date "201104".
One approach is SUMFS but that is not at my disposal (using excel 2003 only).
Another thing I tried is to first filter via inputbox autofilter for the date and then use SUMIF to sum the values if they have the same name. PROBLEM: SUMIF also adds up the invisible cells.
Best would be a vba approach.
Has anyone an Idea? It would be of tromendous help!

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a pivot table.  Then use the Page as a filter for Peter and 201104. That's the fastest way to get to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This formula will sum values based on multiple criteria and will skip filtered rows:
`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(C2:C6,ROW(C2:C6)-MIN(ROW(C2:C6)),,1,1))*(A2:A6="peter")*(B2:B6=201104))`

Data is assumed to be in A1:C6.

Note: This is an array formula--instead of simply pressing Enter, you need to do Ctrl+Shift+Enter. When entered correctly, you'll see curly braces around the formula in the formula bar.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SUBTOTAL` function. When you filter, only the filtered rows are aggregated (depending on the function specified).

The following will "SUM" the range A1:10.

```
=SUBTOTAL(9, A1:A10)
```

Comment: Actually, it should be =SUBTOTAL(109,A1:A10)

The parameter 9 includes hidden rows, 109 ignores them.

Comment: @Psychic: Note the "Remarks" section of the SUBTOTAL help topic: "The SUBTOTAL function ignores any rows that are not included in the result of a filter, no matter which function_num value you use." <http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/subtotal-HP005209288.aspx>

Comment: 9 allows for filtering, not for hidden cells though, and his question did mention "adds up the invisible cells" so I took that to presume hidden rows. 109 would cover both eventualities.